# Update the position of all my text elements in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart with about 50 text labels in it. Each label is in a group with the point on the chart it refers to.

I want to write a function that goes through each of my text elements, checks if their bounding box is overlapping and updates the position of the text element if so (but not the point in the same group).

This is what I have:

```
svg.selectAll("text")
.each(function () {
    var that = this;
    a = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    svg.selectAll("text")
    .each(function () {
        if (this != that) {
            var b = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            if (a.x > b.x - 5 && a.x < b.x + 5) {
                if (a.x < b.x) {
                    //code to move one way
                } else {
                    //code to move other way
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is I don't know how to refer to the text element in the middle of my function to update its x position. I have tried d3.select(a).attr("x",1000) and a.x = 1000 but I can't work out what the syntax is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `text` elements are in your variables `this` and `that`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. If I put          this.attr("x", 50);
 where my comment is, I get:  Uncaught TypeError: this.attr is not a function

Comment: @user3424748 `this` and `that` are `Node` objects. To call `.attr()` on them you have to do `d3.select(this).attr("x", 50)` to get a D3 selection object.